# Silex namespace : class MainController does not exist

Tags: php, class, namespaces, autoload, silex

I try to use Silex Framework, but i have a problem with namespaces I think.

when I instanciate my class MainController i have the following error : 
*Class "MainController" does not exist*

here the namespace declaration in my MainController.php :

```
    namespace App\Controllers;

    use Silex\Application;

    class MainController implements \Silex\ControllerProviderInterface { 
....
```

in my app.php  :

```
$app->mount("/", new \App\Controllers\MainController());
```

And i've an autoload in my composer.json :

```
    "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {"App\\": "app/"}
}
```

scruture of my project is like it :

|--app/
|----app.php
|----controllers/
|-------MainController.php
|--web/
|----index.php

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Did you run `composer update` to update your autoloader, after adding `autoload` section?

Comment: Yes tried  install/update  without success...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem is caused by the way you named your directory `controllers`. According to the documentation about `PSR-4` standard:

> 5) Alphabetic characters in the fully qualified class name MAY be any combination of lower case and upper case.
>
> 6) All class names MUST be referenced in a case-sensitive fashion.

So, rename your directory to `Controllers` and re-run `composer update`.

Also, take a look at [ServiceControllerProvider](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/service_controller.html) about the proper way of setting controller instance as a callback. Passing new instance might not be the best (if not wrong) way of doing things. You should be doing something like:

```
$app->get('/', 'App\\Controllers\\MainController::index');
```

Comment: Using `mount` is very different than using `get`, and OP's using it correctly.

Comment: I wasn't talking about `mount` or `get` (in my case, it's just an example). When the OP manages to load his classes it will most likely get an error because he did not provide a valid callable action. I was simply referering to controller/action part, but point taken.

Comment: I tryed to change controllers by Controllers and run composer update but without success...

Comment: OKAY , i do little changes and now it's work , i don't know why but it's okay lol... So thanks a lot even if I don't know how it's done ^^ . bye , have a great day .

Comment: I was referring to the part of your answer beginning with "Also, take..."